# Extracting common controller functionality into base controller

Tags: angularjs, refactoring, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

The web app I'm working on has a view of a `Person` entity. We have several controllers that perform CRUD operations on data of that Person (e.g. phone numbers, email addresses, etc.). In turn, these controllers are contained within a FormController that gathers all the operations to be performed and actually stores them in the database.

For instance, the code of the **Add** operation for an **email** looks like this:

```
angular.module('people').controller('emailsFormController', 
    ['$scope', 
    function ($scope) {

    $scope.emails = [];
    $scope.emailErrorMessage = "";
    $scope.newEmailAddress = ""; //this is set in the view

    $scope.addNewEmail = function () {
        if (!emailExists($scope.newEmailAddress)) {
            var newEmail = {
                Dto: {
                    Id: -1,
                    EmailAddress: $scope.newEmailAddress,
                    EmailDescription: "No Description",
                },
                State: "Add"
            };
            $scope.emails.push(newEmail);
        }
        else {
            $scope.emailErrorMessage = "The email already exists!";
        }
    };
};
```

As you can imagine, the code that adds a phone number is pretty much the same.
(Except for the variable names and the DTO object...)

How can I extract this common functionality into a base (controller|service)? Which would be more appropriate? I'm new to Angular so I want to know how to architecture apps for maintanibility.

EDIT: I found this article. Will this suit my use case? http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/03/25/AngularJS-A-better-way-to-implement-a-base-controller.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can, maybe, create a factory (service) with a code fragment like this:

```
$scope.addNewFeature = function ( type ) {

    switch ( type ) {

        default:
        case "email": 
            if (!emailExists($scope.newEmailAddress)) {
                var newEmail = {
                    Dto: {
                        Id: -1,
                        EmailAddress: $scope.newEmailAddress,
                        EmailDescription: "No Description",
                    },
                    State: "Add"
                };
                $scope.emails.push(newEmail);
            }
            else {
                $scope.emailErrorMessage = "The email already exists!";
            }

            break;

       case "phone":
            if (!phoneExists($scope.newphoneAddress)) {
                var newPhone = {
                    Dto: {
                        Id: -1,
                        phoneNumber: $scope.newPhoneNumber,
                        phoneDescription: "No Description",
                    },
                    State: "Add"
                };
                $scope.phones.push(newPhone);
            }
            else {
                $scope.phoneErrorMessage = "The phone already exists!";
            }

            break;

    }

};
```

You can also create dynamic function execution, but that'll involve using `eval()` and no one likes that. :)

Another approach can be to have a common function for adding items, and some seperate function to check the item type and morph the request in that way.

```
var getItemType = function( checkVar ) {

    return ( checkVar.indexOf( '@' ) > -1 && checkVar.indexOf( '.' ) > -1 ) ? "email" : "phone"; // Very primitive; just an example.

}

var itemExists = function( item ) {

    return (

        ( getItemType( item ) === "phone" ) ?
            // Check for phone :
            // Check for email

    );

}

$scope.addNewItem = function ( item ) {

    if (!itemExists( item )) {
        var newItem = {
            Dto: {
                Id: -1,
                ItemAddress: $scope.newItemAddress,
                ItemDescription: "No Description",
                ItemType: getItemType( item )
            },
            State: "Add"
        };
        $scope.items.push(newItem);
    }
    else {
        $scope.itemErrorMessage = "The item already exists!";
    }

}
```

Morphing the function:

```
var getItemType = function( checkVar ) {

    return ( checkVar.indexOf( '@' ) > -1 && checkVar.indexOf( '.' ) > -1 ) ? "email" : "phone"; // Very primitive; just an example.

}

var itemExists = function( item ) {

    return (

        ( getItemType( item ) === "phone" ) ?
            // Check for phone :
            // Check for email

    );

}

$scope.addNewItem = function ( item ) {

    var itemExistsF = theFirstFunctionYouWant;

    if ( getItemType( item ) === "phone" ) {
        itemExistsF = theFunctionYouWant;
    } 

    if (!itemExistsF( item )) {
        var newItem = {
            Dto: {
                Id: -1,
                ItemAddress: $scope.newItemAddress,
                ItemDescription: "No Description",
                ItemType: getItemType( item )
            },
            State: "Add"
        };
        $scope.items.push(newItem);
    }
    else {
        $scope.itemErrorMessage = "The item already exists!";
    }

}
```

Comment: I like the second approach. But for example, would it be possible to override the "itemExists" method?

Comment: Yeah! But depending on how exactly do you want to change it. Have a look at the edit,

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and say that prototypal inheritance is probably your best bet.
Here is the article I used for reference
http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/

So if you wanted to create a service to host shared data (a good idea), you can still do that, but would only need to initialize it in the "mainFormController". And by having the children controllers inherit from that controller, they'll have that reference setup.

```
function mainFormController($scope){
    //Core stuff up here
    $scope.OverrideMe = function(){

    };
};

function emailsFormController($scope){
    this.mainFormController($scope);

    $scope.addNewEmail = function () {
        if (!emailExists($scope.newEmailAddress)) {
            var newEmail = {
                Dto: {
                    Id: -1,
                    EmailAddress: $scope.newEmailAddress,
                    EmailDescription: "No Description",
                },
                State: "Add"
            };
            $scope.emails.push(newEmail);
        }
        else {
            $scope.emailErrorMessage = "The email already exists!";
        }
    };

    //OverrideExample
    $scope.OverrideMe = function(){
        //new override function code goes here
    };
};

emailsFormController.prototype = Object.create(mainFormController);

angular.module('people').controller('emailsFormController', ['$scope',emailsFormController]);
```